# jquery classic asp return HTML and recordcount/other data

Tags: jquery, asp-classic

Using Classic ASP to make a JQuery ajax call to an asp page that returns HTML. That works fine. Now I'd like to return not only the HTML but also some numbers, like the recordcount, from the page I call. How do I do that?

This is my AJAX call:

```
function sendCcbRequest(text) {
var jsonToSend = { text: escape(text) };
var jsonToSend={ id: 1, lastname: escape(text) } ;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'test-ajax-handler.asp',
    data: jsonToSend,
    success: function(response) {
        $('#output').append(response);
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("error");
    }
}); // end ajax
```

}

The page that it calls just response.write's out some HTML. I'd like it to also push out a count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

return your data as JSON like:

```
 {"html":"<div>This is your HTML<\/div","count":3}


$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'test-ajax-handler.asp',
    data: jsonToSend,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
        $('#output').append(response.html);
        $('#count').html(response.count);
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could have your ASP page send a custom HTTP Header in the response like:

```
XHR-Count: 5
```

with:

```
Response.AddHeader "XHR-Count", "5"
```

and then fetch this header in the `success` callback:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'test-ajax-handler.asp',
    data: jsonToSend,
    success: function(response, status, xhr) {
        var count = xhr.getResponseHeader('XHR-Count');
        alert(count);
        $('#output').append(response);
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```